# Ffmpeg problems on centOS 5.8 64 bit

Tags: centos, video, conversion, ffmpeg

I did install `ffmpeg` with `winff`, unsuccessfully when I try converting avi to x264, it says I don't have it. When I try to convert mp4 to Xvid I get `unknown encoder 'libxvid'`. It's like nothing really works except avi Msi compatible using `winff`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: used static ffmpeg package for more information check below URL (kernel version should be 2.6.32+) https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the actual ffmpeg installation `yum remove ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel`, you will have to install the DAG RPM repositories which contains huge amount of rpm packages. It’s very easy. Just install the latest rpmforge-release package for your distribution and architecture.

This will automatically install the configuration and GPG keys that are for safely installing RPMforge packages.

## nano -w /etc/yum.repos.d/dag.repo

```
Insert :-

[dag]
name=Dag RPM Repository for Red Hat Enterprise Linux
baseurl=http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el$releasever/en/$basearch/dag
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

Then save the repo file also you can update RPM through rpmforge :-

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS//rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

```
yum update
```

Installing FFMPEG.:-

```
yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
```

If Seems there is some lib problems along the way so in /etc/ld.so.conf add

```
/usr/local/lib
```

also check /etc/ld.so.conf.d and make sure there are no .conf files that may be loading other files.

then

```
ldconfig -v
```